# Host a Python program for remote use

Tags: python, hosting, remote-access, remote-desktop

**Background**
I have developed a python gui using Pyqt5 that interacts with a Sqlite database.
The program runs smoothly when run from terminal but performance is drastically reduced when creating an executable, exe.
The program generates Docx, csv and other file formats.
I don't have any experience with hosting servers or network solutions

**Problem**
I want to give access for a select few, to use the program but restrict them from access to the raw code files (.py). And I don't want to install the program on several machines.
I want users to access the outputted files and be able to export the files.

**Considered Solution 1**
Remote desktop, setting up remote desktop with pythin installed on my home laptop and giving access to a simple exe file that starts the script.
-Concerns
Opening my home network and deploying RDS.

Securing the program files from copying or editing

Performance with multiple users

Capacity for storage if the sql database grows beyond my hard drive.

Ability to send the outputted Docx csv and other files.

**Considered solution 2**
Hosting in a 3rd party cloud, not an option due to sensitivity of data.

**Questions**
Any recommendations on a solution that I should consider?

I am leaning towards RDS, is there functionality limitations and/or security issues I need to consider?

Answer (score 0):

Update, I have deployed a solution using Microsoft remote Desktop and a custom Windows Kiosk made i Windows Configuration Designer. a link to getting started with Windows Configuration Designer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llg09SdJpLI&t=189s

**In the autolaunch RS5 xml statement use .pyw files to restrict access to terminal for the user.

Securing the program files from copying or editing:

- Handeled by Kiosk envirnoment

Performance with multiple users:

- Remote Desktop on Windows 10 Pro only allows for single remote session, so this is still an issue

Capacity for storage if the sql database grows beyond my hard drive.

- Added a remote server

Ability to send the outputted Docx csv and other files.

- Hasnt been an issue ... yet.